# Converting String to Date formate in xls using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to converting the `String (returns string :odb.getCloseDate())` into Date in the below code. But I am not getting the output in this formate `"23/10/2013"` .Please correct me where I am doing the mistake.
In Database table values is in this formate : 2013-06-30  and im retrieving this data through bean i.e. odb.getCloseDate(). Now i need to display this date in this formate i.e 23/10/2013.

```
        HSSFCell row1 = row.createCell((short) j);
        //row1.setCellType(row1.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);

        try
        {
            //row1.setCellValue( Date.parse(odb.getCloseDate()));
            DateFormat formatter;
            Date date;
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            row1.setCellValue(date = formatter.parse(odb.getCloseDate()));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            row1.setCellValue(odb.getCloseDate());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Date and Time Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

`mm` indicates `Minutes`, `MM` indicates `Month`

```
formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

instead of

```
formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Try this,

```
        String dateValue = "2013-06-30"; //consider as your date.
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");// First apply the patern to the incoming date value. Because it doesnt know the actual incming format
        Date actualDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateValue);
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(actualDate));
```

Comment: I Made the changes as per your suggestion. But didn't get the output in this formate  23/10/2013.. Plz help

Comment: remove the cellType row1.setCellType(row1.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC); convert the incoming date as String and set the date as String.

Comment: I commented the line  row1.setCellType(row1.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) in the above code and checked. But no use. Output is not coming as 23/10/2013.

Comment: Above solution worked. Suppose, if it is time stamp like this "2013-07-09 16:09:24.805" how to convert this, to this formate 7/9/2013  4:09:25 PM ?

Comment: Above Solution worked. I got the solution for timeStamp. THANK YOU :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your date format  `mm`   should be  `MM`

Reason

```
m   Minute in hour
```

where as

```
M   Month in year
```

You need `Month in year` not `Minute in hour`.

Then your for formatter becomes

```
formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

[Have a look on different formats here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I corrected the above code. But I am not getting the expected result. Please correct me where I am doing mistake.( The return type string is in the formate odb.getCloseDate()="2013-06-30")

Comment: @WorkWorld Update your post with . Current value of String, expected, and current output

Comment: The date coming from your database is in wrong format. Check this ====>http://ideone.com/8RbIWI